# difference between email_on_failure and on failure callback

Tags: airflow

I am very new to [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) and did some research, but did not find any concrete difference between the below-mentioned terms. I  found that the job done by

- `email_on_failure :True` and
- `on_failure_callback = <some_methods>`- are same.

Can someone just mention the functional difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`email_on_failure` is a boolean DAG argument to set whether to send an email when a **task** has failed.

Example: Airflow will trigger an email to `airflow@example.com` when a task has failed.

```
default_args = {
    ...
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
}
```

`on_failure_callback` is a function that will execute if a **DagRun** has failed.

Example: Airflow will run function `print_hello` when the DagRun has failed.

```
function print_hello():
  print('hello')

default_args = {
    ...
    'on_failure_callback': print_hello
}
```

For a more detailed description of what parameters are assigned to a DAG please see: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html